# What does a Python class object hash to?

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing code that dynamically imports enum classes, and at some point put those enums into a set.
Printing out that set, I was surprised to see the same class twice:

```
{<enum 'FactType'>, <enum 'FactType'>}
```

One comes from a direct import and the other from an indirect import of the same class. It made me wonder: **what is the hash value of a class**?

Since a class is an instance of its metaclass, and `type` is the base metaclass for all classes, I went to look into the `type` [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c), but couldn't really find a definitive answer there.

Comment: Seems like I'll have to answer that one myself. Stay tuned!